# How can I keep background music playing whilst changing Activity?

Tags: android, media-player

My application has some background music playing on a loop, using a `MediaPlayer`. I stop the music in the `onPause` of the Activity so it doesn't keep on playing if the user leaves the application by pressing the Home key, or if they receive a phone call, etc.

However, I now need the music to continue playing seamlessly when the user moves to certain other activities. That is, if they press button A then I add activity A to the stack and the music should continue; however if they press button B then I add activity B to the stack and the music should stop. Similarly the music should continue if they press the phone's Back button to return from activity A to the original activity.

I've tried starting the `MediaPlayer` again in the `onResume` of Activity A, but there's quite a noticeable gap in the music during the transition.

At the moment I've got `onPause` triggering a half-second delay before fading the music out over another quarter of a second; this can be cancelled from within another activity's `onResume`. This means the music stops just about quickly enough when the user's leaving the app; however when the user switches activities I still get a slight pause in the music on some slower devices. Furthermore it feels like a really dirty hack.

Is there a better way?

[Edit: if it helps, the `MediaPlayer` is held in a static class that I can access from anywhere in the application.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution that I can think of offhand if I needed to get this done would be to set a static flag variable in my global `Application` object (let's call it `sStartingNewActivity`). Wherever I'm starting an intent new activity (or pressing "back" from an activity that isn't the entry point, overriding the `onBackPressed` method), I'd set that value to `true`, and have `onPause` not stop the music if that flag is set. I'd set the value back to `false` in every activity's `onCreate`. I don't think a 1-2-second-pause-before-fadeout is a bad way to go, though -- that would actually behave pretty similarly to how it works when the user presses the "home" button in an iOS app that has background music.

EDIT: You can also try a service-based solution that "sniffs" for whether your activities are running by having your activities listen for a specific broadcast; there's some [sample code online](http://www.mannaz.at/codebase/android-activity-foreground-surveillance/) that I haven't tried but it's an interesting approach).